# CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA exception when retrieving Outlook message from Clipboard

Tags: c#, outlook, clipboard

I recently started encountering an exception when pasting a message (not attachment) as a file from Outlook. The code used to work, but I'm not sure what changed.

The exception is

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Data on clipboard is invalid (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800401D3 (CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA))'

The code is

```
using var s = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetData("FileContents") as Stream;
```

Bear in mind that I can successfully get the message name with this

```
using var s = System.Windows.Clipboard.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor") as Stream;
```

Also `Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetFormats()` lists all the formats so they should be there. Any idea what might be wrong?

I've searched through all mentions of CLIPBRD_E_BAD_DATA online and nothing helps. SharpClipboard doesn't detect the message file either.

Comment: Can the file be pasted in Windows Explorer? Are both Outlook and your code running in the same security context (no "Run As Administrator")?

Comment: Yes, Explorer can paste it and I can paste it afterwards from Explorer to the app (because I check FileDrop format as well), but not from Outlook to the app. Both are running as normal users as far as I can tell.